# How to get rid of ants without harming the tree

Tags: fruit-trees, ants

Several days ago I found in my garden hunderds of big black ants.

What's worst: I traced them and found that their hole is at the base of my young Macademia tree.

Can I get rid of the ants without harming the tree?